Signalr Data Received but not updating my global variable in Context - React App
I have a React application that receives a SingalR message via RabbitMQ. I get the notification in the console with all the correct data. The problem is, I am trying to update my global Variable in my Context with the information from the signalr data which then will be used on my front end. I am new to Signal R but it seems that I am doing something right as I am able to get my data in my tracking event just fine in the console. I am hoping if I share my code here, someone can hightlight what I might have missed in my Context. Thank you in advance.
MapComponent.tsx
const MapComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const { patrols, updatePatrol, fetchPatrols, loading: patrolsLoading } = usePatrolContext();
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState('all');
  const [isSidebarCollapsed, setIsSidebarCollapsed] = useState(false);
  const [selectedPatrol, setSelectedPatrol] = useState<Patrol | null>(null);
  const [zoomLevel, setZoomLevel] = useState(5.8);
  const signalRConnectedRef = useRef(false);
  const mapRef = useRef<L.Map>(null);
  const latestSignalRDataRef = useRef<any[]>([]);
  const markersRef = useRef<{ [key: string]: L.Marker }>({});

  useEffect(() => {
    log.info('Global patrols data in MapComponent:', globalPatrolsData);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleSignalRData = (data: any) => {
      log.info('SignalR data received in MapComponent:', data);
      const updatedData = Array.isArray(data) ? data : [data];

      updatedData.forEach(async (item) => {
        const updatedPatrol: Partial<Patrol> = {
          GpsId: item.DeviceId,
          speed: item.Speed,
          battery: item.Battery,
          kmOdometer: item.KmOdometer,
          latitude: item.Latitude,
          longitude: item.Longitude,
          degrees: item.Degrees,
          altitude: item.Altitude,
          ambientLightValue: item.AmbientLightValue,
          satellite: item.Satellite,
          signalValid: item.SignalValid,
          historyData: item.HistoryData,
          gps_date: item.GpsDate,
          address: await ReverseGeocode(item.Latitude, item.Longitude),
        };
        updatePatrol(updatedPatrol as Patrol);
      });
    };

    signalRService.subscribe('trackingReceived', handleSignalRData);

    return () => {
      signalRService.unsubscribe('trackingReceived', handleSignalRData);
    };
  }, [updatePatrol]);

  const subscribeToPatrolUpdates = useCallback((patrolIds: string[]) => {
    signalRService.trackDevices(patrolIds);
  }, []);

  const initializeSignalR = useCallback(async () => {
    if (signalRConnectedRef.current) {
      log.info('SignalR already connected, skipping initialization');
      return;
    }

    try {
      log.info('Connecting to SignalR');
      await signalRService.connect({
        url: process.env.REACT_APP_SIGNALR_URL || 'http://localhost:5000/signalr',
        hub: 'trackingHub',
        qs: { username: 'developer' },
        listenToMethods: ['trackingReceived']
      });

      signalRConnectedRef.current = true;

      const isConnected = await signalRService.isConnectionEstablished();
      if (isConnected && patrols.length > 0) {
        const patrolIds = patrols.map((p: Patrol) => p.GpsId);
        subscribeToPatrolUpdates(patrolIds);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error initializing SignalR:', error);
    }
  }, [patrols, subscribeToPatrolUpdates]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAndInitialize = async () => {
      try {
        if (!patrolsLoading && patrols.length === 0) {
          await fetchPatrols();
        }
        await initializeSignalR();
      } catch (error) {
        log.error('Error during fetch and initialization:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchAndInitialize();

    return () => {
      signalRService.removeAllListeners('trackingReceived');
      signalRService.disconnect();
      signalRConnectedRef.current = false;
    };
  }, [initializeSignalR, patrolsLoading, fetchPatrols, patrols.length]);

PatrolContext.tsx:
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect, useCallback, ReactNode } from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';
import { Patrol } from '../types';
import { createIcon } from '../utils/iconUtils';
import log from '../logger';
import signalRService from '../services/signalRService';

interface PatrolContextType {
  patrols: Patrol[];
  icons: { [key: string]: L.Icon };
  loading: boolean;
  error: string | null;
  fetchPatrols: () => Promise<void>;
  updatePatrol: (updatedPatrol: Patrol) => void;
}

interface PatrolProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

let globalPatrolsData: Patrol[] = [];

const PatrolContext = createContext<PatrolContextType | undefined>(undefined);

export const PatrolProvider: React.FC<PatrolProviderProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [patrols, setPatrols] = useState<Patrol[]>([]);
  const [icons, setIcons] = useState<{ [key: string]: L.Icon }>({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const fetchPatrols = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/patrols`);
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch patrols');
      }
      const data: Patrol[] = await response.json();
      setPatrols(data);
      globalPatrolsData = data;
      log.info('Global patrols data updated:', globalPatrolsData);

      const newIcons: { [key: string]: L.Icon } = {};
      data.forEach((patrol) => {
        const key = `${patrol.statusId}-${patrol.patrolType}`;
        if (!newIcons[key]) {
          newIcons[key] = createIcon(patrol.statusId, patrol.patrolType);
        }
      });
      setIcons(newIcons);

      setLoading(false);
    } catch (err: unknown) {
      setError(err instanceof Error ? err.message : 'An unknown error occurred');
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    const fetchInitialPatrols = async () => {
      try {
        await fetchPatrols();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching initial patrols:', error);
      }
    };

    const handleSignalRData = (data: any) => {
      log.info('SignalR data received in Patrol Context:', data);
      const updatedData = Array.isArray(data) ? data : [data];

      setPatrols((prevPatrols) => {
        const newPatrols = prevPatrols.map((patrol) => {
          const updatedPatrol = updatedData.find((u) => u.DeviceId === patrol.GpsId);
          if (updatedPatrol) {
            return {
              ...patrol,
              speed: updatedPatrol.Speed,
              battery: updatedPatrol.Battery,
              kmOdometer: updatedPatrol.KmOdometer,
              latitude: updatedPatrol.Latitude,
              longitude: updatedPatrol.Longitude,
              degrees: updatedPatrol.Degrees,
              altitude: updatedPatrol.Altitude,
              ambientLightValue: updatedPatrol.AmbientLightValue,
              satellite: updatedPatrol.Satellite,
              signalValid: updatedPatrol.SignalValid,
              historyData: updatedPatrol.HistoryData,
              gps_date: updatedPatrol.GpsDate,
            };
          }
          return patrol;
        });

        globalPatrolsData = newPatrols;
        log.info('Global patrols data after SignalR update:', globalPatrolsData);
        return newPatrols;
      });
    };

    fetchInitialPatrols();

    signalRService.subscribe('trackingReceived', handleSignalRData);

    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
      signalRService.unsubscribe('trackingReceived', handleSignalRData);
    };
  }, [fetchPatrols]);

  const updatePatrol = useCallback((updatedPatrol: Patrol) => {
    setPatrols((prevPatrols) => {
      const newPatrols = prevPatrols.map((patrol) =>
        patrol.GpsId === updatedPatrol.GpsId ? { ...patrol, ...updatedPatrol } : patrol
      );
      globalPatrolsData = newPatrols;
      log.info('Global patrols data updated in updatePatrol:', globalPatrolsData);
      return newPatrols;
    });
  }, []);

  const contextValue: PatrolContextType = {
    patrols,
    icons,
    loading,
    error,
    fetchPatrols,
    updatePatrol,
  };

  return <PatrolContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</PatrolContext.Provider>;
};

export const usePatrolContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(PatrolContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error('usePatrolContext must be used within a PatrolProvider');
  }
  return context;
};

export { globalPatrolsData };

signalRService.tsx:
import 'signalr';
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
import log from '../logger';

declare var jQuery: any;

const ConnectionState = {
  Connecting: 0,
  Connected: 1,
  Reconnecting: 2,
  Disconnected: 4
};

interface HubConnectionOptions {
  url: string;
  qs?: any;
  hub: string;
  listenToMethods: string[];
}

class SignalRService {
  public trackingEvent: EventEmitter;
  public connectionStateChanged: EventEmitter;
  public connection: SignalR.Hub.Connection | null = null;
  private proxy: SignalR.Hub.Proxy | null = null;
  private isConnected: Promise<boolean>;
  private connectedResolver: (value: boolean) => void = () => {};

  constructor() {
    this.trackingEvent = new EventEmitter();
    this.isConnected = new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {
      this.connectedResolver = resolve;
    });
    this.connectionStateChanged = new EventEmitter();
  }

  public async connect(options: HubConnectionOptions): Promise<void> {
    if (this.connection && this.connection.state === ConnectionState.Connected) {
      log.info('Connection already exists, skipping connection');
      return;
    }

    const connection = jQuery.hubConnection();
    connection.url = options.url;
    if (options.qs) {
      connection.qs = options.qs;
    }

    connection.reconnected(() => {
      this.connectedResolver(true);
      log.info(`Now reconnected to hub ${options.hub}, connection ID= ${connection.id}`);
    });

    connection.disconnected(() => {
      this.connectedResolver(false);
      log.info('Disconnected from hub, attempting to reconnect...');
      this.attemptReconnect(options);
    });

    connection.stateChanged((state: SignalR.StateChanged) => {
      log.info(`Connection state changed to: ${state.newState}`);
      this.connectionStateChanged.emit('stateChanged', state);
    });

    this.proxy = connection.createHubProxy(options.hub);
    this.proxy?.on('trackingReceived', (message) => this.onTrackingReceived(message));

    try {
      await connection.start();
      this.connection = connection;
      this.connectedResolver(true);
      log.info(`Now connected to hub ${options.hub}, connection ID= ${connection.id}`);
    } catch (error) {
      log.error('Could not connect', error);
      this.connectedResolver(false);
    }
  }

  public async isConnectionEstablished(): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.isConnected;
  }

  private attemptReconnect(options: HubConnectionOptions, attempt: number = 1) {
    const maxAttempts = 5;
    const delay = Math.min(1000 * Math.pow(2, attempt), 30000); // Exponential backoff with max 30 seconds

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.connection?.state === ConnectionState.Disconnected) { 
        log.info(`Attempting to reconnect (attempt ${attempt})...`);
        this.connection.start()
          .done(() => {
            log.info(`Reconnected to hub ${options.hub}, connection ID= ${this.connection?.id}`);
            this.connectedResolver(true);
          })
          .fail(() => {
            if (attempt < maxAttempts) {
              this.attemptReconnect(options, attempt + 1);
            } else {
              log.error('Failed to reconnect after maximum attempts');
            }
          });
      }
    }, delay);
  }

  public disconnect() {
    if (this.connection) {
      this.connection.stop();
      log.info('Disconnected from hub');
    }
    this.connection = null;
    this.proxy = null;
  }

  private onTrackingReceived(message: any) {
    log.info('Received tracking data:', message);
    if (Array.isArray(message) && message.length) {
      message = message[0];
    }
    this.trackingEvent.emit('trackingReceived', message);
    log.info('Tracking event emitted with message:', message);
  }

  // check this
  public trackDevices(devices: Array<string>) {
    log.info('trackDevices called with devices:', devices);
    log.info('Connection state:', this.connection?.state);
    if (this.connection?.state === ConnectionState.Connected && devices && devices.length > 0) {
      // log.info('Invoking trackDevices with devices:', devices);
      this.proxy?.invoke('trackDevices', devices);
    } else {
      log.warn('Cannot track devices: connection not established or no devices provided');
    }
  }

  public untrackDevices(devices: Array<string>) {
    if (this.connection?.state === ConnectionState.Connected && devices && devices.length > 0) {
      this.proxy?.invoke('untrackDevices', devices);
    } else {
      log.warn('Cannot untrack devices: connection not established or no devices provided');
    }
  }

  public subscribe(eventName: string, listener: (...args: any[]) => void) {
    log.info(`Subscribing to event ${eventName}`);
    this.trackingEvent.on(eventName, listener);
  }

  public unsubscribe(eventName: string, listener: (...args: any[]) => void) {
    log.info(`Unsubscribing from event ${eventName}`);
    this.trackingEvent.off(eventName, listener);
  }

  public removeAllListeners(eventName: string) {
    log.info(`Removing all listeners for event ${eventName}`);
    this.trackingEvent.removeAllListeners(eventName);
  }
}

const signalRService = new SignalRService();
export default signalRService;

So my dilema is how to immediately take that incomming message from signalr and update my patrol data. Any help, much appreciated. Thank you.

ANSWER:
I ended up having to incorporate my patrols directly into my signalr function calls via the context. I hope this helps someone else who runs into the same issue. Here are my updated codes:
MapComponent.tsx:
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef, useCallback, useMemo } from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, useMapEvents } from 'react-leaflet';
import L, { LatLngExpression, CRS } from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import Sidebar from '../Components/Sidebar';
import CustomZoomControl from '../Components/BottonComponents/CustomZoomControl';
import RefreshButton from '../Components/BottonComponents/RefreshButton';
import signalRService from '../services/signalRService';
import GeoJsonLayer from '../MapLayers/GeoJsonLayer';
import MunicipalitiesGeoJsonLayer from '../MapLayers/MunicipalitiesGeoJsonLayer';
import PatrolMarkerCluster from '../Components/PatrolMarkerCluster';
import { Patrol } from '../types';
import LoadingComponent from '../Components/LoadingComponent';
import Waves from '../assets/OndasAzules2.png';
import Ai27Logo from '../assets/ai27logo.png';
import MexicoMunicipalities from '../assets/municipalities.geojson';
import MexicoStates from '../assets/states.geojson';
import { usePatrolContext, globalPatrolsData } from '../Context/PatrolContext';
import log from '../logger';
import { ReverseGeocode } from '../utils/reverseGeocode';

const MapComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const { patrols, updatePatrol, fetchPatrols, loading: patrolsLoading } = usePatrolContext();
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState('all');
  const [isSidebarCollapsed, setIsSidebarCollapsed] = useState(false);
  const [selectedPatrol, setSelectedPatrol] = useState<Patrol | null>(null);
  const [zoomLevel, setZoomLevel] = useState(5.8);
  const signalRConnectedRef = useRef(false);
  const mapRef = useRef<L.Map>(null);
  const latestSignalRDataRef = useRef<any[]>([]);
  const markersRef = useRef<{ [key: string]: L.Marker }>({});

  useEffect(() => {
    log.info('Global patrols data in MapComponent:', globalPatrolsData);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleSignalRData = (data: any) => {
      log.info('SignalR data received in MapComponent:', data);
      const updatedData = Array.isArray(data) ? data : [data];

      updatedData.forEach(async (item) => {
        const updatedPatrol: Partial<Patrol> = {
          GpsId: item.DeviceId,
          speed: item.Speed,
          battery: item.Battery,
          kmOdometer: item.KmOdometer,
          latitude: item.Latitude,
          longitude: item.Longitude,
          degrees: item.Degrees,
          altitude: item.Altitude,
          ambientLightValue: item.AmbientLightValue,
          satellite: item.Satellite,
          signalValid: item.SignalValid,
          historyData: item.HistoryData,
          gps_date: item.GpsDate,
        };
        updatedPatrol.address = await ReverseGeocode(item.Latitude, item.Longitude);
        updatePatrol(updatedPatrol as Patrol);
      });
    };

    signalRService.subscribe('trackingReceived', handleSignalRData);

    return () => {
      signalRService.unsubscribe('trackingReceived', handleSignalRData);
    };
  }, [updatePatrol]);

  const subscribeToPatrolUpdates = useCallback((patrolIds: string[]) => {
    signalRService.trackDevices(patrolIds);
  }, []);

  const initializeSignalR = useCallback(async () => {
    if (signalRConnectedRef.current) {
      log.info('SignalR already connected, skipping initialization');
      return;
    }

    try {
      log.info('Connecting to SignalR');
      await signalRService.connect({
        url: process.env.REACT_APP_SIGNALR_URL || 'http://localhost:5000/signalr',
        hub: 'trackingHub',
        qs: { username: 'developer' },
        listenToMethods: ['trackingReceived']
      });

      signalRConnectedRef.current = true;

      const isConnected = await signalRService.isConnectionEstablished();
      if (isConnected && patrols.length > 0) {
        const patrolIds = patrols.map((p: Patrol) => p.GpsId);
        subscribeToPatrolUpdates(patrolIds);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error initializing SignalR:', error);
    }
  }, [patrols, subscribeToPatrolUpdates]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAndInitialize = async () => {
      try {
        if (!patrolsLoading && patrols.length === 0) {
          await fetchPatrols();
        }
        await initializeSignalR();
      } catch (error) {
        log.error('Error during fetch and initialization:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchAndInitialize();

    return () => {
      signalRService.removeAllListeners('trackingReceived');
      signalRService.disconnect();
      signalRConnectedRef.current = false;
    };
  }, [initializeSignalR, patrolsLoading, fetchPatrols, patrols.length]);

  const initializeMap = useCallback(() => {
    if (mapRef.current) {
      const map = mapRef.current;
      log.info('Map created');
      const targetZoom = 5.8;
      const targetCenter: LatLngExpression = [24.50, -99.50];
      map.setView(targetCenter, targetZoom, { animate: false });

      map.on('load', () => {
        log.info('Map loaded');
      });

      map.on('zoomend', () => {
        const zoom = map.getZoom();
        setZoomLevel(zoom);
      });

      map.on('click', () => {
        setSelectedPatrol(null);
        Object.values(markersRef.current).forEach((marker) => {
          if (marker.isPopupOpen()) {
            marker.closePopup();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }, []);

  const ZoomHandler = () => {
    useMapEvents({
      zoomend: (e) => {
        setZoomLevel(e.target.getZoom());
      },
    });
    return null;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    initializeMap();
  }, [initializeMap]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mapRef.current) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        mapRef.current?.invalidateSize();
      }, 300);
    }
  }, [isSidebarCollapsed]);

  const handleFilterClick = (newFilter: string) => {
    setFilter(newFilter);
  };

  const handleRefreshClick = async () => {
    try {
      await fetchPatrols();
      const patrolIds = patrols.map((p: Patrol) => p.GpsId);
      log.info('Refreshed patrol IDs:', patrolIds);
      subscribeToPatrolUpdates(patrolIds);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
  };

  const filterConditions: { [key: string]: (patrol: Patrol) => boolean } = {
    available: (patrol) => patrol.statusId === 1,
    in_process: (patrol) => patrol.statusId === 2,
    in_maintenance: (patrol) => patrol.statusId === 4,
    finished: (patrol) => patrol.statusId === 3,
  };

  const filterPatrols = useCallback((patrol: Patrol) => {
    const filterFunction = filterConditions[filter];
    return filterFunction ? filterFunction(patrol) : true;
  }, [filter]);

  const handleMarkerClick = useCallback(async (patrol: Patrol | null, marker?: L.Marker) => {
    log.info('Marker clicked with patrol:', patrol);
    log.info('Global Patrols data in handleMarkerClick:', globalPatrolsData);

    if (patrol) {
      const matchingData = globalPatrolsData.find((item) => item.GpsId === patrol.GpsId);
      log.info('Matching SignalR data:', matchingData);

      if (matchingData) {
        const updatedPatrol = { ...patrol, ...matchingData };
        const address = await ReverseGeocode(updatedPatrol.latitude, updatedPatrol.longitude);
        updatedPatrol.address = address;
        log.info('Updated patrol with SignalR data:', updatedPatrol);
        setSelectedPatrol(updatedPatrol);
      } else {
        log.info('No matching SignalR data found for patrol:', patrol);
        setSelectedPatrol(patrol);
      }
    } else {
      setSelectedPatrol(null);
    }
  }, []);

  const initialZoom = 5.8;
  const initialCenter: LatLngExpression = [24.50, -99.50];

  const filteredPatrols = useMemo(() => {
    return patrols.filter(filterPatrols);
  }, [patrols, filterPatrols]);

  return (
    <div className="h-screen flex overflow-hidden">
      <Sidebar
        onFilterClick={handleFilterClick}
        onRefreshClick={handleRefreshClick}
        isCollapsed={isSidebarCollapsed}
        toggleSidebar={() => setIsSidebarCollapsed(!isSidebarCollapsed)}
        selectedPatrol={selectedPatrol}
        filteredPatrols={filteredPatrols}
      />
      <div className="relative w-full h-full">
        <MapContainer
          center={initialCenter}
          zoom={initialZoom}
          style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
          crs={CRS.EPSG3857}
          zoomControl={false}
          minZoom={4}
          maxZoom={18}
          zoomSnap={0.1}
          wheelPxPerZoomLevel={60}
          whenReady={initializeMap}
          ref={mapRef}
        >
          <ZoomHandler />
          {zoomLevel >= 9 && (
            <TileLayer
              url="https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png"
              attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            />
          )}
          {zoomLevel < 9 && (
            <>
              <GeoJsonLayer url={MexicoStates} />
              <MunicipalitiesGeoJsonLayer url={MexicoMunicipalities} />
            </>
          )}
          <PatrolMarkerCluster
            onMarkerClick={handleMarkerClick}
            selectedPatrol={selectedPatrol}
            zoomLevel={zoomLevel}
            filter={filterPatrols}
            markersRef={markersRef}
          />
          <CustomZoomControl />
          <RefreshButton onClick={handleRefreshClick} />
        </MapContainer>
        <img
          src={Waves}
          alt="Background Waves"
          className="absolute bottom-0 object-cover pointer-events-none"
          style={{ width: '709.125px', height: '339.75px', zIndex: 1000, right: '-100px' }}
        />
        <img
          src={Ai27Logo}
          alt="AI27 Logo"
          className="absolute bottom-[33px] right-[23px] pointer-events-none"
          style={{ width: '76px', height: 'auto', zIndex: 10 }}
        />
        <LoadingComponent isLoading={patrolsLoading} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MapComponent;

PatrolContext.tsx:
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect, useCallback, ReactNode, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';
import { Patrol } from '../types';
import { createIcon } from '../utils/iconUtils';
import log from '../logger';

interface PatrolContextType {
  patrols: Patrol[];
  icons: { [key: string]: L.Icon };
  loading: boolean;
  error: string | null;
  fetchPatrols: () => Promise<void>;
  updatePatrol: (updatedPatrol: Patrol) => void;
  setPatrols: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Patrol[]>>;
}

interface PatrolProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

let globalPatrolsData: Patrol[] = [];
let setPatrolsRef: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Patrol[]>>;

const PatrolContext = createContext<PatrolContextType | undefined>(undefined);

export const PatrolProvider: React.FC<PatrolProviderProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [patrols, setPatrols] = useState<Patrol[]>([]);
  const [icons, setIcons] = useState<{ [key: string]: L.Icon }>({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  // Store the setPatrols function in the ref
  setPatrolsRef = setPatrols;

  const fetchPatrols = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/patrols`);
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch patrols');
      }
      const data: Patrol[] = await response.json();
      setPatrols(data);
      globalPatrolsData = data;
      log.info('Global patrols data updated:', globalPatrolsData);

      const newIcons: { [key: string]: L.Icon } = {};
      data.forEach((patrol) => {
        const key = `${patrol.statusId}-${patrol.patrolType}`;
        if (!newIcons[key]) {
          newIcons[key] = createIcon(patrol.statusId, patrol.patrolType);
        }
      });
      setIcons(newIcons);

      setLoading(false);
    } catch (err: unknown) {
      setError(err instanceof Error ? err.message : 'An unknown error occurred');
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;

    const fetchInitialPatrols = async () => {
      try {
        await fetchPatrols();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching initial patrols:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchInitialPatrols();

    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, [fetchPatrols]);

  const updatePatrol = useCallback((updatedPatrol: Patrol) => {
    setPatrols((prevPatrols) => {
      const newPatrols = prevPatrols.map((patrol) =>
        patrol.GpsId === updatedPatrol.GpsId ? { ...patrol, ...updatedPatrol } : patrol
      );
      globalPatrolsData = newPatrols;
      log.info('Patrol updated:', updatedPatrol);
      log.info('Global patrols data updated:', globalPatrolsData);
      return newPatrols;
    });
  }, []);

  const contextValue: PatrolContextType = {
    patrols,
    icons,
    loading,
    error,
    fetchPatrols,
    updatePatrol,
    setPatrols,
  };

  return (
    <PatrolContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </PatrolContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const usePatrolContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(PatrolContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error('usePatrolContext must be used within a PatrolProvider');
  }
  return context;
};

// Define updatePatrols outside the component
export const updatePatrols = (data: any) => {
  log.info('Updating patrols with SignalR data:', data); // Log data

  const updatedData = Array.isArray(data) ? data : [data];

  setPatrolsRef((prevPatrols) => {
    const newPatrols = prevPatrols.map((patrol) => {
      const updatedPatrol = updatedData.find((u) => u.DeviceId === patrol.GpsId);
      if (updatedPatrol) {
        return {
          ...patrol,
          speed: updatedPatrol.Speed,
          battery: updatedPatrol.Battery,
          kmOdometer: updatedPatrol.KmOdometer,
          latitude: updatedPatrol.Latitude,
          longitude: updatedPatrol.Longitude,
          degrees: updatedPatrol.Degrees,
          altitude: updatedPatrol.Altitude,
          ambientLightValue: updatedPatrol.AmbientLightValue,
          satellite: updatedPatrol.Satellite,
          signalValid: updatedPatrol.SignalValid,
          historyData: updatedPatrol.HistoryData,
          gps_date: updatedPatrol.GpsDate,
        };
      }
      return patrol;
    });

    globalPatrolsData = newPatrols;
    log.info('Global patrols data after SignalR update:', globalPatrolsData);
    return newPatrols;
  });
};

export { globalPatrolsData };

and finally the signalRService.tsx:
import 'signalr';
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
import log from '../logger';
import {updatePatrols} from '../Context/PatrolContext';

declare var jQuery: any;

const ConnectionState = {
  Connecting: 0,
  Connected: 1,
  Reconnecting: 2,
  Disconnected: 4
};

interface HubConnectionOptions {
  url: string;
  qs?: any;
  hub: string;
  listenToMethods: string[];
}

class SignalRService {
  public trackingEvent: EventEmitter;
  public connectionStateChanged: EventEmitter;
  public connection: SignalR.Hub.Connection | null = null;
  private proxy: SignalR.Hub.Proxy | null = null;
  private isConnected: Promise<boolean>;
  private connectedResolver: (value: boolean) => void = () => {};

  constructor() {
    this.trackingEvent = new EventEmitter();
    this.isConnected = new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {
      this.connectedResolver = resolve;
    });
    this.connectionStateChanged = new EventEmitter();
  }

  public async connect(options: HubConnectionOptions): Promise<void> {
    if (this.connection && this.connection.state === ConnectionState.Connected) {
      log.info('Connection already exists, skipping connection');
      return;
    }

    const connection = jQuery.hubConnection();
    connection.url = options.url;
    if (options.qs) {
      connection.qs = options.qs;
    }

    connection.reconnected(() => {
      this.connectedResolver(true);
      log.info(`Now reconnected to hub ${options.hub}, connection ID= ${connection.id}`);
    });

    connection.disconnected(() => {
      this.connectedResolver(false);
      log.info('Disconnected from hub, attempting to reconnect...');
      this.attemptReconnect(options);
    });

    connection.stateChanged((state: SignalR.StateChanged) => {
      log.info(`Connection state changed to: ${state.newState}`);
      this.connectionStateChanged.emit('stateChanged', state);
    });

    this.proxy = connection.createHubProxy(options.hub);
    this.proxy?.on('trackingReceived', (message) => this.onTrackingReceived(message));

    try {
      await connection.start();
      this.connection = connection;
      this.connectedResolver(true);
      log.info(`Now connected to hub ${options.hub}, connection ID= ${connection.id}`);
    } catch (error) {
      log.error('Could not connect', error);
      this.connectedResolver(false);
    }
  }

  public async isConnectionEstablished(): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.isConnected;
  }

  private attemptReconnect(options: HubConnectionOptions, attempt: number = 1) {
    const maxAttempts = 5;
    const delay = Math.min(1000 * Math.pow(2, attempt), 30000); // Exponential backoff with max 30 seconds

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.connection?.state === ConnectionState.Disconnected) { 
        log.info(`Attempting to reconnect (attempt ${attempt})...`);
        this.connection.start()
          .done(() => {
            log.info(`Reconnected to hub ${options.hub}, connection ID= ${this.connection?.id}`);
            this.connectedResolver(true);
          })
          .fail(() => {
            if (attempt < maxAttempts) {
              this.attemptReconnect(options, attempt + 1);
            } else {
              log.error('Failed to reconnect after maximum attempts');
            }
          });
      }
    }, delay);
  }

  public disconnect() {
    if (this.connection) {
      this.connection.stop();
      log.info('Disconnected from hub');
    }
    this.connection = null;
    this.proxy = null;
  }

  private onTrackingReceived(message: any) {
    log.info('Received tracking data:', message);
    if (Array.isArray(message) && message.length) {
      message = message[0];
    }
    this.trackingEvent.emit('trackingReceived', message);
    log.info('Tracking event emitted with message:', message);
    updatePatrols(message);
  }

  // check this
  public trackDevices(devices: Array<string>) {
    log.info('trackDevices called with devices:', devices);
    log.info('Connection state:', this.connection?.state);
    if (this.connection?.state === ConnectionState.Connected && devices && devices.length > 0) {
      // log.info('Invoking trackDevices with devices:', devices);
      this.proxy?.invoke('trackDevices', devices);
    } else {
      log.warn('Cannot track devices: connection not established or no devices provided');
    }
  }

  public untrackDevices(devices: Array<string>) {
    if (this.connection?.state === ConnectionState.Connected && devices && devices.length > 0) {
      this.proxy?.invoke('untrackDevices', devices);
    } else {
      log.warn('Cannot untrack devices: connection not established or no devices provided');
    }
  }

  public subscribe(eventName: string, listener: (...args: any[]) => void) {
    log.info(`Subscribing to event ${eventName}`);
    this.trackingEvent.on(eventName, listener);
  }

  public unsubscribe(eventName: string, listener: (...args: any[]) => void) {
    log.info(`Unsubscribing from event ${eventName}`);
    this.trackingEvent.off(eventName, listener);
  }

  public removeAllListeners(eventName: string) {
    log.info(`Removing all listeners for event ${eventName}`);
    this.trackingEvent.removeAllListeners(eventName);
  }
}

const signalRService = new SignalRService();
export default signalRService;

Maybe not the most perfect solution but it gets me closer to the final product.
